# Bootstrap Navbar Not Responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've recently added a Bootstrap navbar to my site.  And it's not being responsive.  When I emulate a mobile screen on Firefox, I see no button for a dropdown menu.

I've double checked to see if I linked all the necessary Bootstrap files and Jquery file fine, and they do.

The HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="inlineParagraph navbartext"><a href="/internet" color="white"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download navIcon fa-lg"></i>View Our Internet Packages!</a></p>
        <li class="inlineParagraph navbarspacer"><a href="/phone"><i class="fa fa-phone navIcon fa-lg"></i>Phone Services!</a></p>
        <li class="inlineParagraph navbarspacer"><a href="/Televison"><i class="fa fa-television navIcon fa-lg"></i>Television Programs!</a></p>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

And my Navbar CSS rules:

```
.inlineParagraph {
  float:left;
  display:inline;
}
.navbartext {
      padding-top: 17px;
      padding-left: 175px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 17px;
}
.navbarspacer{
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

What my navbar looks like after the updated code:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about `navbar-default` or `navbar-inverse` class.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
```

And instead of using `p` tags in your `ul` you should use list items (`li`).

```
<li class="inlineParagraph navbartext"><a href="/internet" color="white"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download navIcon fa-lg"></i>View Our Internet Packages!</a></li>
```

Comment: It's not working fine for me... so obviously I've got somethign conflicting with it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `</p>` with `</li>`.

```css
.inlineParagraph {

  float: left;

  display: inline;

}

.navbartext {

  padding-top: 17px;

  padding-left: 175px;

  text-align: center;

  font-size: 17px;

}

.navbarspacer {

  padding-top: 17px;

  padding-left: 50px;

  text-align: center;

  font-size: 17px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="inlineParagraph navbartext"><a href="/internet" color="white"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download navIcon fa-lg"></i>View Our Internet Packages!</a>
          </li>
          <li class="inlineParagraph navbarspacer"><a href="/phone"><i class="fa fa-phone navIcon fa-lg"></i>Phone Services!</a>
            </li>
            <li class="inlineParagraph navbarspacer"><a href="/Televison"><i class="fa fa-television navIcon fa-lg"></i>Television Programs!</a>
              </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```